# Regular expression for floats on grep

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

```
I0709 13:45:33.848619  3415 upgrade_proto.cpp:1044] Attempting to upgrade input file specified using deprecated 'solver_type' field (enum)': models/model
I0709 20:02:09.081399  3415 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 101, loss = 2.25779
I0709 20:02:09.081477  3415 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 2.25779 (* 1 = 2.25779 loss)
I0709 20:02:09.081495  3415 sgd_solver.cpp:106] Iteration 101, lr = 0.01
I0709 20:02:20.067615  3415 solver.cpp:228] Iteration 102, loss = 2.22583
I0709 20:02:20.067740  3415 solver.cpp:244]     Train net output #0: loss = 2.22583 (* 1 = 2.22583 loss)
```

From a file like the above, I need the numbers 2.25779 and 2.22583 in this case, and dump each one on a line on a new file.

I've tried something like:

```
cat file.txt | grep -P 'loss = .*[0-9]\n' > res.csv
```

That doesn't match anything tho and I don't know how to get more specific (only the number not the loss =).

So a:

```
 cat res.csv
```

Should show the output:

```
2.25779

2.22583
```

Comment: Doesn't match anything? It does match `loss = 2.25779`.

Comment: i dont get any matches, the res.csv is empty after i run the command

Comment: Just match `loss\s*=\s*\d` and be done with it..

Comment: This `\n` part of your regex is the problem. Take it out ! And doesn't  _grep_ like some regex delimiters like `/../` ?

Comment: @sln no, the whole argument passed to grep is the regexp `grep 'regexp' file` so no additional delimiters are used. `awk` and `sed` use delimiters when they are doing regexp matching since, unlike `grep`, they do more than just matching a regexp.

Comment: Anyway, grep is just going to return true or false, it's not going to output any capture groups.

Comment: Like all UNIX tools, grep doesn't return anything. It prints any matching strings and it exists with status success or fail. It's important not to confuse exit statuses success (zero) / fail (non-zero) with boolean values true (one) / false (zero). You are correct it doesn't support capture groups.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work with any sed on any OS:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*loss = \([0-9.]*\)$/\1/p' file
2.25779
2.22583
```

Only GNU grep would support the options/syntax you are trying to use and no grep supports what you would need to achieve your goal of only outputting part of the matching text (that would require capture groups which grep does not have).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is going to help you:

```
(?<!:)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)
```

It will match the floats, but **won't match the microseconds**, like there:

```
20:02:09.081477
```

Comment: i only need that one specific float from those lines 2.25779 not the time one, but thanks.

Comment: Very few tools will recognize `\d` as meaning a digit and only GNU grep will support PCREs so you should state which tool(s) this will work with.

Comment: @Member That's what I've stated, highlighted in case you've missed it.

Comment: @Member Have you checked whether my regex works for you or not?

Comment: It's still using PCRE syntax which GNU grep might be able to handle but idk if any other grep will.

Comment: cat text.txt | grep -P '(?<!:)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)' > exp.csv that copies text.txt on exp.csv, not what i need

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture groups with ()

```
loss = (\d*\.\d*)
```

- `()` is the captured group
- `\d*` matches any number with any length
- `\.` matches the character **.** literally

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/aX0lC1/1)'s a life demo

Comment: Very few tools will recognize `\d` as a digit and no grep supports capture groups. Specifying a regexp without the tool (sed, grep, awk, perl, whatever) that can execute it is practically useless since they all support different regexp flavors with different options and delimiters.